# Understanding MVC-5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I created a new `ASP.NET MVC-5` application with `Individual User Accounts` and then updated all the `Nuget packages` in the solution. Now I'm trying to follow some of the guidelines shown in some tutorials but I encountered some problems. 
The first one is that a class called `ApplicationRoleManager` which is being used throughout the application wasn't created (the `ApplicationUserManager` was created).
The second problem is more about `Entity-Framework`: I've seen that for seeding the database with a user and role many people create a static constructor in the `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
```

So I added it, and the implementation of the `ApplicationDbInitializer` is:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    //Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "admin@admin.com";
        const string password = "Admin@123456";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
        {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
    }
```

After adding everything I opened the `Package Manager Console` and typed `Enable-Migrations`, then `Add-Migration someName` and then `Update-Database`.
the results were that the database was created successfully but no data was inserted to the database.
After noticing the data wasn't inserted I moved the `Seed` logic to the Index method of the home controller and the data was inserted after running the application.
I also needed to add this line:   `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);`
 to the `Startup.Auth.cs` file.
So my questions are:

1. Do I really need to enter the `ApplicationRoleManager` class
   manually?
2. How do I make the `seed` method work?

**UPDATE**
I've changed the `Seed` method to:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        //since there is no ApplicationRoleManager (why is that?) this is how i create it
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        const string name = "admin@admin.com";
        const string password = "Admin@123456";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }
        //app hangs here...
        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
        {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

So now, the Admin role is created but when getting to `var user = userManager.FindByName(name);` the application hangs with no exception or any message...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using migrations you can use the built in initializer and the `Seed` method:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new 
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, 
    APPLICATION.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

and in `APPLICATION.Migrations.Configuration` (this was created by the `Enable-Migrations` command):

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    // seed logic
}
```

As a role manager you can also use the `RoleManager<ApplicationRole>` base implementation.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a custom initializer?

Comment: Of course you can - just extend `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` instead of `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, BUT the stuff you are doing is not meant to be placed there. Take a look at `IdenitityConfig.cs` and `AuthConfig.cs`/`Startup.Auth.cs`...

Comment: Could you please explain the part after the "BUT"?

Comment: If you created a new MVC 5 project with the `Individual User Accounts` setting you should have those two files created for you under `~/App_Start/` including all that setup logic for the user-/role-manger "in the right place" (it is not required to be there, but "best practice")...

Comment: So  besides the setup logic (which I guess you mean everything in `ApplicationUserManager`'s `Create()` method) the seeding of the data should happen there too?

Answer (score 3):

I also was a bit confused about hanging of application in this case. The problem can be solved in this way

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUserManager>(db));
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
```

Comment: This was it. Took me 4 hours fiddling with this.. hate this M$ crap !!

Answer (score 2):

And for anyone using the ApplicationUser with Integer foreign key, the code is this one:

```
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context));
var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(context));
```

Comment: Glad I could help,  since I've too lost a lot of time with this 'simple' issue.

Answer (score 1):

This works great for default MVC 5 project.

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the solutions posted address the issue of the app hanging on the call of `userManager.FindByName(name)`.  I'm running into the same problem.  It worked a few hours ago on my local.  I published to Azure and it started hanging.  When I tested my local again it all of a sudden started hanging at that step.  No error is returned and no timeout (at least after waiting 10-15 minutes).  **Does anyone have any tips to address Yoav's ultimate question?**

I have some other very simple seeding processes that run before adding roles, and `db.Foo.AddOrUpdate(foo)` calls are running without error, but not actually saving anything to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a deeply unpleasant half day dealing with this. I finally managed to get the damn thing to fire:

```
public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

            //var userManager = HttpContext.Current
            //    .GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            //var roleManager = HttpContext.Current
            //    .GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

            var roleStore = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>(context);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole, int>(roleStore);
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(userStore);   
...
```

It's the end of an *extremely* long day, and I suspect someone's going to tell me why I shouldn't do this. The rest of my Seed method fires beautifully, however, using non-async methods (FindByName/Create).

Answer (score 0):

Sir goobering,
You struggles have helped me get passed this problem, I had to do it a little different though.

```
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        //var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        //var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

        const string name = "admin@example.com";
        const string password = "Admin@123456";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        ***var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));***

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }
```