# InitializeIdentityForEF freezes and does not create the default admin account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

When I first started the project, I had no errors.

Now, when I run the project and it creates the database, it keeps loading and loading. If I stop and run again, everything works fine, except my admin account was not created.

I'm using Identity 2.0.

Here is the code:

```
 public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "admin@mundogato.org";
        const string password = "Admin@1234";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new ApplicationRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name)) {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue where OWIN wasn't ready at that point. Try this code for the managers, assuming ApplicationDbContext derives from the Identity Context:

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
```

See [Understanding MVC-5 Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120942/understanding-mvc-5-identity)